# cURL HTTP Request with PHP (Routific API)

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to make an HTTP Request in PHP using cURL. The Request goes to the Routific (Route Optimization) API -> https://docs.routific.com/v1.3.1/docs
The idea is to send a JSON with different waypoints and get an optimal route back. Unfortunately, I get the following error when executing the code:

```
{"error":"Missing network"}
```

My Code looks as follows:

```
<?php                                                                  
$data_string = json_encode(file_get_contents('Routes.json'));                                                                          

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.routific.com/v1/vrp");                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                                                                               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Authorization: bearer API_KEY')                                                                       
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                                                                  

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

What is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: i think your problem is Routes.json , having the .json extension, i bet it IS already json_encoded, so you corrupt the data when you run it through json_encode, now its double-encoded, which an invalid format the api can't read - try just removing the json_encode call

Comment: also, don't use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST for POST, use CURLOPT_POST=>true

Comment: thanks a lot! now it works. stupid mistake :P